# Swift Color space different on iPhone 5 compared to iPhone 5s or 5se

Tags: swift, nan, cgcontext, cgcolorspace

I click on an image to return a pixel colour. This works fine but I have found out that it doesn't work on iPhone 5. It works on iPhone 5s, 5SE and all other sizes. I do not understand why.
The following code give red and blue as nan on iPhone 5.

```
//  returns the color data of the pixel at the currently selected point

func getPixelColorAtPoint(_ point:CGPoint)-> UIColor{
 let pixel = UnsafeMutablePointer<CGFloat>.allocate(capacity: 4)
 let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
 let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
 if let context = CGContext(data: pixel, width: 1, height: 1, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue){
   context.translateBy(x: -point.x, y: -point.y)
   torsoImage.layer.render(in: context)
 }
 let pColor:UIColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(pixel[0])/255.0, green: CGFloat(pixel[1])/255.0, blue: CGFloat(pixel[2])/255.0, alpha: CGFloat(pixel[3])/255.0)

 pixel.deallocate(capacity: 4)
 print("Colour touch is \(pColor)")
 return pColor
}

//Colour touch is UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace nan 1.94443e+12 nan 1.48678e-42
```

Comment: Most probably, `pixel` should be an array of `UInt8`, not `CGFloat`.

Comment: This works but how can I mark this as an answer (its a comment)?

Comment: Is this due to the iPhone 5 having smaller memory than the others for holding array of floats compared to Ints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CGContext(data: pixel, width: 1, height: 1, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4, ...)
```

creates a graphics context which is backed up by four *bytes* (one for each color component), therefore you have to pass an array of `UInt8`:

```
let pixel = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 4)
```

What happens in your case is that only the first 4 bytes of the first `CGFloat` will be set, all remaining data is *undefined* (and might result in `nan` or some arbitrary value). Even if you don't get
`nan`, the values will be wrong.

Comment: Brilliant fixed it. Thanks for the explanation also.